# How to prevent garbage collection in Python when an interactive plot runs in the background (Python, matplotlib)?

Tags: python, garbage-collection, matplotlib-widget

I have a code that uses matplotlib and the Button widget.
It all works well, but when this code is written as a function, the buttons stop working.
This is because after the function runs, the button objects are being removed by the garbage collector.

Here is an example of the **code that does not work well**:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Button

def fun():
    def Prev(x):
        print("Prev")
    def Next(x):
        print("Next")

    freqs = np.arange(2, 20, 3)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)
    t = np.arange(0.0, 1.0, 0.001)
    s = np.sin(2*np.pi*freqs[0]*t)
    l, = plt.plot(t, s, lw=2)
    axprev = plt.axes([0.7, 0.05, 0.1, 0.075])
    axnext = plt.axes([0.81, 0.05, 0.1, 0.075])
    bnext = Button(axnext, 'Next')
    bnext.on_clicked(Next)
    bprev = Button(axprev, 'Previous')
    bprev.on_clicked(Prev)

fun()
```

Here is my **non-so-elegant solution**:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Button

def fun():
    def Prev(x):
        print("Prev")
    def Next(x):
        print("Next")

    freqs = np.arange(2, 20, 3)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)
    t = np.arange(0.0, 1.0, 0.001)
    s = np.sin(2*np.pi*freqs[0]*t)
    l, = plt.plot(t, s, lw=2)
    axprev = plt.axes([0.7, 0.05, 0.1, 0.075])
    axnext = plt.axes([0.81, 0.05, 0.1, 0.075])
    bnext = Button(axnext, 'Next')
    bnext.on_clicked(Next)
    bprev = Button(axprev, 'Previous')
    bprev.on_clicked(Prev)
    return bnext,bprev

b1,b2=fun()
```

Is there a better, best-practice solution for this kind of problem?

Comment: Is Index() a custom function you're using? I'm trying to reproduce the issue, but keep getting a not defined error on Index().

Comment: @JordanPaldino Hi Jordan, this line ("...Index()") should have been removed, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you correctly assumed the key is to keep alive a reference to the button in the outer scope. If you don't want to return a collection of buttons what you could do is, to add the buttons as attribute of the figure. I wouldn't say there is a best practice for such a thing of just plotting one figure, and for a more complex UI there might be better solutions. But this code solves this specific issue without having to explicitly returning the button references.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Button
import  matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")


def fun():
    def Prev(x):
        print("Prev")
    def Next(x):
        print("Next")

    freqs = np.arange(2, 20, 3)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)
    t = np.arange(0.0, 1.0, 0.001)
    s = np.sin(2*np.pi*freqs[0]*t)
    l, = plt.plot(t, s, lw=2)
    axprev = plt.axes([0.7, 0.05, 0.1, 0.075])
    axnext = plt.axes([0.81, 0.05, 0.1, 0.075])
    bnext = Button(axnext, 'Next')
    bnext.on_clicked(Next)
    bprev = Button(axprev, 'Previous')
    bprev.on_clicked(Prev)
    fig.bnext = bnext    # add button references to figure object
    fig.bprev = bprev


if __name__ == "__main__":
    fun()
    plt.show()
```